# Whats wrong with this specified code in this java code?

Tags: java

```
class Pointgrejen{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        int[] a = new int[5];
        a[3] = 7;

        Point[] b = new Point[5];
        b[3].x = 7; 

        System.out.print(a[3]);
        System.out.print(b[3]);
    }
}
```

Why isn't the program executing? Point is a java class in java, but is the error in this code that I havent defined what type of data the array should hold in the point array? Or whats the bigger issue with this code?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Are you getting a nullpointerexception?

Comment: `new Point[5]` doesn't create 5 points. It creates an array of nulls that you can store instances of `Point` in.

Comment: I get that but i dont see where the problem is

Answer (score 1):

You created the array, so the array values will be `null` by default.

Means `b[3]` will be `null`, so you will get `NullPointerException` in below line of code:

```
Point[] b = new Point[5];
b[3].x = 7;
```

So to fix it create objects and assign them to array:

```
b[3] = new Point();
b[3].x = 7
```

Comment: So problem is that i need to first create b[3] to be an object?

Comment: @MrMiyagi yes, create and use it

Answer (score 0):

You created the points array, but is filled with nulls so to assign b[3].x = 7; you must first do b[3] = new Point();

Comment: So i have to make b[3] and object first basically